# Difficulty Rendering Bangla Text in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bangla-font

I'm encountering issues while attempting to print Bangla text in Matplotlib. Despite trying various methods, I've been unable to resolve the problem. Here's the code snippet I'm using, tried to print some bangla words in plot to show the bangla text rendering problem :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from matplotlib import font_manager as fm

bangla_font_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf"
font = fm.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=bangla_font_path)

text_list = ["পেরু", "রুদ্র", "ক্ষতি", "যুক্তবর্ণ", "পৃথিবী"]

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))

for i, text in enumerate(text_list):
    plt.text(0.5, 0.5 - i * 0.1, text, ha='center', va='center', fontproperties=FontProperties(fname=bangla_font_path))
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[The output is getting like this... not as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTXNs.png)

I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue so that Bangla text can be rendered correctly in Matplotlib. Thank you for your help.

Comment: And what is the desired output? I see the five words correctly printed in the screen. What is wrong with them? You haven't specified what the problem is.

Comment: the expected output is 
পেরু
রুদ্র
ক্ষতি
যুক্তবর্ণ
পৃথিবী
like this

Comment: @Elerium115 please see the output context is broken or not printed correctly..

Comment: In the `plt.text` command the first value is the x-position (horizontal) of the text and the second value is the y-position (vertical). You are changing the y-position for each item in the `text_list`, so I would expect to see the text printed one above the other as you are seeing. If you want them next to each other, change the x-position and keep the y-position the same.

Comment: Thank you @MattPitkin ...  yes you are right... but I am facing with the font problem

Comment: Alternatively, if you just want the text printed as পেরু রুদ্র ক্ষতি যুক্তবর্ণ পৃথিবী, you don't need to loop over each item. You could instead just have one call to `plt.text` with: `plt.text(0.5, 0.5, " ".join(text_list), ha='center', va='center', fontproperties=FontProperties(fname=bangla_font_path))`.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see now that the characters in your output plot are not rendered same as you input text. I can only suggest trying some different Bangla font ttf files to see how they compare.

Comment: I have tried many ttf file... others show like ☐☐☐ ...
only this shows better than others... but also not correct :)

Comment: To use Bangla script on matplotlib you need OpenType font rendering support, which the existing backends of matplotlib do not support. You need to install mplcairo and use that as the matplotlib backend. But you need its dependencies: libraqm, froibidi and harfbuzz. Pillow uses the same stack.

Comment: An example using Kannada on macOS: https://github.com/enabling-languages/python-i18n/blob/main/notebooks/kn_demographics_pandas_matplotlib.ipynb